# Is it possible to launch the Apple Pay NFC from my app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, sdk, nfc

I would like to capture the NFC payment details in an app and was hoping this would be available if the NFC payment was launched from my app. I just need to know the amount paid, and merchant.

Going through Apple's docs, all I can see is software implementations of the Apple Pay with Touch ID, I can't see any references to integrate the Apple Pay NFC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible as Apple's implementation is meant to conceal this data. That's the reason you can't find anything in their docs about it. Apple Pay via NFC is initiated by the contactless payment terminal and not "launched from [your] app". The data like the tokenized Primary Account Number (PAN), Cardholder Name, Expiration date, etc is sent from the Apple device to the payment terminal and up to the cloud via the merchant's infrastructure. Check page 19 of the [EMV Overview Guide](https://www.dropbox.com/s/twlhkm0uq6y7lzp/EMVCo_A_Guide_to_EMV_2011051203091992.pdf?dl=0) to get an idea. The Apple device unlocks the data from the Secure Element (after TouchID access granted) and shuttles it over NFC and most likely won't ever expose these details to the App layer. The approach runs inline with their statement "Keep your purchases private." If the transaction is approved the payment terminal will send a Transaction Certificate (TC) over the NFC link to alert the Apple device the payment was successful. No amount paid or merchant name is sent over with the TC according to the spec. It might also be worth reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25753473/reading-nfc-tags-with-iphone-6-ios-8/26637240#26637240) to better understand how the Apple devices only act as contactless cards and not readers.

The best way to get involved with the customer transaction is offering an InApp payment experience at the store. Whether it be through iBeacons or geolocation, launching the retail app in context can allow customers to purchase through Apple Pay InApp rather than NFC. This provides you more opportunity to get the merchant and transaction amount since your app is in control vs the NFC stack. It's tricky to cover the checkout workflow but doable.

I hope this info is useful and guides you to some other options to get what you need done.