# APDU request through NFC in iPhone 6?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nfc, applepay

Using an android mobile device I could read the card details(authorized by the client with touch id) from iphone6, for payment transaction through NFC. I got it working through the APDU request. 
APDU request

`Send : 00 A4 04 00 07 A0 00 00 00 03 10 10 00`

and response

`Response: 6F 39 84 07 A0 00 00 00 03 10 10 A5 2E 9F 38 1B 9F 66 04 9F 02 06 9F 03 06 9F 1A 02 95 05 5F 2A 02 9A 03 9C 01 9F 37 04 9F 4E 14 BF 0C 0D 9F 4D 02 14 01 9F 5A 05 11 08 40 08 40 90 00`

Now my concern is, can I send the same APDU request from iPhone 6 through NFC or some other means to get the appropriate response from another iPhone 6? Is it possible?

Though I can understand that NFC chip in iPhone6 does not allow iPhone-Iphone NFC communication, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25753473/reading-nfc-tags-with-iphone-6-ios-8) question clearly states that THERE IS NO WAY to read passive NFC tags using an iPhone6. Okay, but there are comments saying it might be possible after september2014?

There must be some way to do this, Please do give out your thoughts on this. Thanks.

Comment: There is currently no way for third party apps to access NFC in any way shape or form. You can't do anything relating to NFC.

Comment: Okay, so there is no way yet-thanks mate!

Answer (score 0):

As I pointed out in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25753473/reading-nfc-tags-with-iphone-6-ios-8), the iPhone6 is not designed for Discovery mode or to act as a master in Peer-to-peer mode. You can however use a mobile NFC reader to proxy NFC data between 2 iPhones. [Flomio offers a line of mobile and PC compatible NFC readers](http://flomio.com/product-category/readers/) that you may consider.

Also worth mentioning, there's another option in reading unique data off the iPhone6 that may address your needs as well. Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31480805/is-apple-watch-detected-by-an-rfid-reader) for details.