# Passing data to iOS app from the received NFC data

Tags: ios, nfc, hardware

Can I pass data, from the received NFC data, to my iOS app using some kind of antenna or alike?

I know Apple confirmed that NFC chip is limited to Apple Pay only for at least one year, but they did not indicate whether the company would continue to limit the developers from accessing it after that time.

The thing is, we have this kind of idea... using NFC to pass the data to a receiver then this receiver will pass the data to our iPad app. I don't know if this is even possible, so any ideas is much appreciated thanks.

*references*:

- http://www.cultofmac.com/296093/apple-confirms-iphone-6-nfc-apple-pay/
- [Reading NFC Tags with iPhone 6 / iOS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25753473/reading-nfc-tags-with-iphone-6-ios-8)

*edit*:

This is not actually a duplicate of one of my references above 'cause I just want to know if there are any **hardware** or something like antenna to pass the received data to my iOS app.

Actually, API and the hardware itself is my concern. After a few reads, I confirmed that there's still **no docs about the API** for this one.

Comment: there is no api for interacting with the NFC reader according to your sources so i would say its not possible

Answer (score 0):

One possible option might be to use a separate RFID reader with BT interface. One possible source is Chafon in China, but there may be others as well.

I have not used it and don't know how easy or difficult it may be to use such a device for NFC. It might involve some coding on the phone to create the NFC protocol stack there.

[Chafon GRH350](http://www.chafonrfid.com/productdetails.aspx?pid=637)

Comment: Hi there, I'm developing iPad app and using CHAFON products, but not using NFC, the client wants to use handheld reader that connects to app. I have the source code, but I'm new to iOS app dev.. the device is CF-U909