# NFC Integeration in ios application

Tags: ios, swift, nfc, iphone-6

Is there any Documentation or API Available that will help in creating NFC based Application for IPhone 6 and 6s Device in IOS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading NFC Tags with iPhone 6 / iOS 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25753473/reading-nfc-tags-with-iphone-6-ios-8)

Answer (score 2):

At the moment (May 2016) there is no public API to access the NFC hardware, and there is no 'undocumented hidden' API either.

So no, you can't build NFC based applications on IOS right now.

This may change in the future.