# iPhone newbie: is possible to use NFC on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, swift, nfc

I'm looking to start to develop an iPhone app, and I'm looking for if I can have access to the NFC chip. I've read when the iPhone 6 was released that the NFC was not able for the developers

Thanks

Comment: I don't know about iOS10, but since I didn't heard about it, at least until iOS9, even if the iDevice possess a NFC Chip, developer can't access it. It's only purpose is for Apple Pay.

Comment: For what I've seen.. looks like still is being available just for apple pay.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading NFC Tags with iPhone 6 / iOS 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25753473/reading-nfc-tags-with-iphone-6-ios-8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what I've seen.. looks like still is being available just for apple pay.

Answer (score 0):

CoreNFC is introduced in iOS 11 SDK for reading NFC Tags

[Apple Documentation of CoreNFC](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corenfc)

for more information:
[CoreNFC for card emulation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44385724/corenfc-for-card-emulation/44385940#44385940)