# CoreNFC for card emulation?

Tags: ios, nfc, ios11

CoreNFC is introduced in iOS 11 SDK. can CoreNFC be used for Smart Card emulation on iOS?
[Apple Documentation of CoreNFC](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corenfc)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For Smart Card Emulation we need to **send** card's data (like PAN, CVV2, ...) through NFC module.
According to Apple's Documentation CoreNFC only allows NFC module to **read** Near Field Communication (NFC) tags of types 1 through 5 that contain data in the NFC Data Exchange Format (NDEF).

So it seems the answer is NO at the moment.

> Your app can read tags to give users more information about their physical environment and the real-world objects in it. For example, your app might give users information about products they find in a store or exhibits they visit in a museum.
>
> Using Core NFC, you can read Near Field Communication (NFC) tags of types 1 through 5 that contain data in the NFC Data Exchange Format (NDEF). To read a tag, your app creates an NFC NDEF reader session and provides a delegate. A running reader session polls for NFC tags and calls the delegate when it finds tags that contain NDEF messages, passing the messages to the delegate. The delegate can read the messages and handle conditions that can cause a session to become invalid.

[Apple's CoreNFC Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corenfc)

Comment: iPhone's NFC hardware is complete but iOS limits it.  For example, the wallet app(Apple Pay) obviously works in card emulation mode.  Apple at this moment doesn't want others to have the ability to create an NFC wallet app.