# How to parse NFC data of Type U

Tags: ios, swift, parsing, nfc

I am trying to `parse` the payload from a formatted `NFC chip` but I am having a problem when it comes to `record.type == U`

I am using an Android phone with app `NXP writer`, to write my NFC chips.
I get everything for `record.type == T`, but when I get `record.type == U`, I having some difficulties.

The idea that I found online is, that converting the `data to hexString` and `checking the first 2 numbers`, then you could categorise the following categories that a URI can have.

[iOS 11 - How does one read/parse the NDEF Message from CoreNFC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44445159/ios-11-how-does-one-read-parse-the-ndef-message-from-corenfc?answertab=votes#tab-top)

examples:

1. 0x00 N/A. No prepending is done
2. 0x01 http://www.
3. 0x02 https://www.
4. 0x03 http://
5. 0x04 https://
6. 0x05 tel:
7. 0x06 mailto:
8. 0x07 ftp://anonymous:anonymous@
9. 0x08 ftp://ftp.

etc

hexString = "02676f6f676c652e636f6d"

substring = "02"

Then we have `https://www` and we add the String from the payload, and open safari (or what ever we want to do).

`The problem comes when I want to read a NFC Tag/chip that contains Tel, mailto, geo, sms so far.`

`The code is 3 digits` 006 instead of 2 digits as I read online. And not only that, if I decide to have a geolocation, `I get 006 which is the same with mailto code`. Of course I can solve this problem with more code but since there are solutions that they check only those codes, is there something that I could do, or am I doing something wrong?

Questions:

1. Is there an issue with NXP writer and I am facing this problem?
2. Does the NFC coding have been changed?
3. Is my logic correct ?

Here is my code:

```
    func readerSession(_ session: NFCNDEFReaderSession, didDetectNDEFs messages: [NFCNDEFMessage]) {
    session.invalidate()


    for message in messages{

        for record in message.records{

            guard record.payload.count > 0 else {
                print("Record payload doesn't contain any data in the memory")
                session.invalidate()
                return
            }

            guard let NFCTypeFromTag = String(data: record.type, encoding: .utf8) else{
                print("Unable to detect the Type")
                session.invalidate()
                return
            }

            guard let nfcTypeInput = NFCType(rawValue: NFCTypeFromTag) else {
                print("nfc enum problem")
                session.invalidate()
                return
            }

            switch nfcTypeInput{
            case .T:
                guard let NFCStringFromPayload = String(data: record.payload.advanced(by: 3), encoding: .utf8) else {
                    return
                }
                NFCString = NFCStringFromPayload
            case .U:
                guard let NFCStringFromPayload = String(data: record.payload, encoding: .utf8) else{
                    print("Error: Unable to convert record.payload to String")
                    return
                }

                let hexString = record.payload.hexEncodedString()
                let indexEndFromHexString = hexString.index(hexString.startIndex, offsetBy: 2)

                let substring = hexString[hexString.startIndex ..< indexEndFromHexString]

                print("NFCString : \(NFCStringFromPayload)")
                print("HexString : \(hexString)")
                print("Substring : \(substring)")

                if substring == "00"{
                    let indexEndOfHexStringCase00 = hexString.index(hexString.startIndex, offsetBy: 3)
                    let substringCase00 = hexString[hexString.startIndex..<indexEndOfHexStringCase00]
                    if substringCase00 == "005" {
                        print("Tel:")
                    }else if substringCase00 == "006"{
                        print("mailto:")
                    }else if substringCase00 == "007" {
                        print("sms")
                    }
                }else if substring == "01"{
                    print("http://www")
                }else if substring == "02"{
                    print("https://www")
                }

                NFCString = NFCStringFromPayload

           case .Sp:
                break
            }
            NFCArray.append(NFCString!)
            tableView.reloadData()
            print("NFC String : \(NFCString)")

        }
    }
```

Apple has a terrible documentation on CoreNFC.

Is there any similar solution that someone has implement.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't understand the case of "00", and "006", but instead of using String conversion, you can do: `let prefix = record.payload.prefix(1); let rest = record.payload.dropFirst(1); switch prefix: case case Data(bytes: [0x02]): if let restString = String(data: rest, encoding: .utf8) { let final = "https://www." + restString }`, and add all your switch cases.

Comment: First Thanks for the answer. Case 00 means that code is probably 3 digits instead of 2. `hexString  = 00736d733a39303632363231343f626f64793d686920` That means substringOf2 give us 00 so look for extra digit 007. But I got an Android phone and downloaded an other App and there it works perfectly as it should with substring 2 as the answer that I posted from stack overflow. So I believe it is just a problem of NXP Writer for those cases.

Comment: A solution would be to use a method for analyzing that string, and if it has a prefix "00", then remove the first one, and call yourself (recursive). There is an issue then because if it's "Data", then it has to be a "even" count in the String length (0 to 255 values, 0x00 to 0xFF, you can't really cut it in half, the "end" might cause an issue).

Comment: And what's supposed to be the value behind "00736d733a39303632363231343f626f64793d686920"?

Comment: I am quiet new on NFC and I Believe it should be  0736d733a39303632363231343f626f64793d686920. With a less 0 in front. I am using an other app to write tags and so far all the URI options can be categorised by the first 2 digits of the hexString. I am using this as a guide http://austinblackstoneengineering.com/nfc-p2p-basics/ and here you could find all the different options of URI. But I am not sure 100% sure. So far it looks like that. Do you have any experience ?

Comment: It's not valid then, because according to the doc it should be using encoding UTF8 but it returns nil.

Comment: The above it is just an example to emphasise on the code in the beginning. Writing with the new android app for mailto I get this as a hexString 0670616e6f734073682e6e6f3f7375626a6563743d686926626f64793d6e6663207375636b73 . This starts with 06 not 006 as I got from the previous app

Comment: @PS The "00" at the beginning is just exactly what it is supposed to be -- the prefix code that indicates that there is no prefix. In your example, "00736d733a39303632363231343f626f64793d686920", the remaining string contains the complete (unabbreviated) URI "sms:90626214?body=hi ".

Comment: @MichaelRoland You are right. The problem is that the documentation that I found and the result from the programmed NFC from app to app might differ. So I got confused. But you are right. Thanks

Comment: @PS Well, using the prefix for abbreviation is not mandatory. Hence, an app may choose to either use a well-known prefix or to set the prefix to zero and encode the full URI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Data` directly, no need to use `String` hex conversion.

```
func parseURINFC(_ data: Data) -> String? {
    let prefix = data.prefix(1)
    let rest = data.dropFirst(1)

    switch prefix {
    case Data(bytes: [0x00]):
        return nil
    case Data(bytes: [0x01]):
        guard let restString = String(data: rest, encoding: .utf8) else { return nil }
        return "http://www." + restString
    case Data(bytes: [0x02]):
        guard let restString = String(data: rest, encoding: .utf8) else { return nil }
        return "https://www." + restString
    case Data(bytes: [0x03]):
        guard let restString = String(data: rest, encoding: .utf8) else { return nil }
        return "http://" + restString
    case Data(bytes: [0x04]):
        guard let restString = String(data: rest, encoding: .utf8) else { return nil }
        return "https://" + restString
    case Data(bytes: [0x05]):
        guard let restString = String(data: rest, encoding: .utf8) else { return nil }
        return "tel://" + restString
    case Data(bytes: [0x06]):
        guard let restString = String(data: rest, encoding: .utf8) else { return nil }
        return "mailto://" + restString
    case Data(bytes: [0x07]):
        guard let restString = String(data: rest, encoding: .utf8) else { return nil }
        return "ftp://anonymous:anonymous@" + restString
    case Data(bytes: [0x08]):
        guard let restString = String(data: rest, encoding: .utf8) else { return nil }
        return "ftp://ftp." + restString
    default:
        return nil
    }
}
```

Concerning the `006-` or `007-` prefix, according to the link you gave (http://austinblackstoneengineering.com/nfc-p2p-basics/), it's not valid. Event after trying to convert the rest using UTF8 (as it should since it's a URI) it returns nil.

Comment: Thanks @Larme. This is a very nice solution. It looks like there are some issues from app to app, when you write on a NFC Chip.

Comment: You've got the main idea that you can use subdata (`prefix()`/`dropFrist()`) and compare `Data`. From there, you can use an extension on `Data` to let have them name: `extension Data { static let httpwww = Data(bytes: [0x01]) ... }` if you want, etc.