# i can't find .entitlements file in xcode 9.4

Tags: ios, react-native-ios, xcode9.4

**Prepare your Xcode project**

*Add the NFC capability key to your .entitlements file*

```
<key>
    com.apple.developer.nfc.readersession.formats
</key>
<array>
    <string>NDEF</string>
</array>
```

Comment: Does [this old answer help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44418402/243245) ? "If your project does not have an entitlement file, let Xcode create one for you by just activating and then subsequently deactivating any capability from within Xcode -> Project Targets -> Capabilities." If not, can you give us some more context e.g. where you got those instructions from? (You've pasted that as your question without comment or quote formatting, but I assume they're instructions you've got from somewhere else?)

Comment: this is the easiest way to add an entitlements file to your application