# How to detect Mifare Plus chip with CoreNFC

Tags: ios, swift, nfc, mifare, core-nfc

I want to detect Mifare Plus card. But whenever I get the Scan View, nothing happens. Nor the error callback or the success block get called. Is there a way to read this cards?

Card dump:

> ** TagInfo scan (version 4.23) 2019-08-08 13:05:13 ** Report Type: External
>   -- IC INFO ------------------------------
>
> ## IC manufacturer: NXP Semiconductors
>
> ## IC type: MIFARE Plus X (MF1PLUS60)
>
> -- NDEF ------------------------------
>
> ## No NDEF data storage present: Maximum NDEF storage size after format: 716 bytes
>
> -- EXTRA ------------------------------
>
> ## Memory size: 2 kB
>
> - 32 sectors, with 4 blocks per sector
> - 128 blocks, with 16 bytes per block
>
>   ## Security Level detected: Security Level 1
>
> ## ATS historical bytes details: NXP IC information coding Chip type: MIFARE Plus Memory size: Unspecified Chip version: Released Chip
>
> generation: Unspecified Virtual Card Selection capability:
>   * VCS, VCSL and SVC supported
>   * All Security Levels supported
>   -- FULL SCAN ------------------------------
>
> ## Technologies supported: MIFARE Classic compatible ISO/IEC 14443-3 (Type A) compatible ISO/IEC 14443-2 (Type A) compatible
>
> ## Android technology information: Tag description:
>
> - TAG: Tech [android.nfc.tech.NfcA, android.nfc.tech.MifareClassic, android.nfc.tech.NdefFormatable]
> - Maximum transceive length: 253 bytes
> - Default maximum transceive time-out: 618 ms
>
>   ## Detailed protocol information: ID: 04:6D:19:8A:CE:49:80 ATQA: 0x4400 SAK: 0x08 ATS: 0x0C75778002C1052F2F01BCD600000816
> - Max. accepted frame size: 64 bytes (FSCI: 5)
> - Supported receive rates:
>
>   - 106, 212, 424, 848 kbit/s (DR: 1, 2, 4, 8)
> - Supported send rates:
>
>   - 106, 212, 424, 848 kbit/s (DS: 1, 2, 4, 8)
> - Different send and receive rates supported
> - SFGT: 302.0 us  (SFGI: 0)
> - FWT: 77.33 ms  (FWI: 8)
> - NAD not supported
> - CID supported
> - Historical bytes: 0xC1052F2F01BCD6 |..//...|
>
>   ## Memory content: Sector 0 (0x00) [00] r--  04 6D 19 8A CE 49 80 08 44 00 12 01 11 00 08 16 |.m...I..D.......| [01] rW-  00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>
> 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 |................| [02] rwi  00 00 00 00 00
>   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 |................| [03] WXW 
>   A0:A1:A2:A3:A4:A5 7C:37:88 00 XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
>            MAD access key                (unknown key) Sector 1 (0x01) [04] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- [05] ???  --
>   -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- [06] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- [07] ???  XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX --:--:-- -- XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
>            (unknown key)                 (unknown key)
>
> Sector 2 (0x02) [08] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
>   -- [09] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- [0A] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- [0B] ???  XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX --:--:-- -- XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
>            (unknown key)                 (unknown key)
>
> Sector 3 (0x03) [0C] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
>   -- [0D] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- [0E] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- [0F] ???  XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX --:--:-- -- XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
>            (unknown key)                 (unknown key)
>
> Sector 4 (0x04) [10] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
>   -- [11] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- [12] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- [13] ???  XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX --:--:-- -- XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
>            (unknown key)                 (unknown key)
>
> Sector 5 (0x05) [14] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
>   -- [15] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- [16] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- [17] ???  XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX --:--:-- -- XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
>            (unknown key)                 (unknown key)
>
> Sector 6 (0x06) [18] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
>   -- [19] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- [1A] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- [1B] ???  XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX --:--:-- -- XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
>            (unknown key)                 (unknown key)
>
> Sector 7 (0x07) [1C] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
>   -- [1D] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- [1E] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- [1F] ???  XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX --:--:-- -- XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
>            (unknown key)                 (unknown key)
>
> Sector 8 (0x08) [20] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
>   -- [21] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- [22] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- [23] ???  XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX --:--:-- -- XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
>            (unknown key)                 (unknown key)
>
> Sector 9 (0x09) [24] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
>   -- [25] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- [26] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- [27] ???  XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX --:--:-- -- XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
>            (unknown key)                 (unknown key)
>
> Sector 10 (0x0A) [28] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
>   -- -- [29] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- [2A] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- [2B] ??? 
>   XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX --:--:-- -- XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
>            (unknown key)                 (unknown key)
>
> Sector 11 (0x0B) [2C] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
>   -- -- [2D] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- [2E] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- [2F] ??? 
>   XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX --:--:-- -- XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
>            (unknown key)                 (unknown key)
>
> Sector 12 (0x0C) [30] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
>   -- -- [31] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- [32] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- [33] ??? 
>   XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX --:--:-- -- XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
>            (unknown key)                 (unknown key)
>
> Sector 13 (0x0D) [34] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
>   -- -- [35] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- [36] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- [37] ??? 
>   XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX --:--:-- -- XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
>            (unknown key)                 (unknown key)
>
> Sector 14 (0x0E) [38] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
>   -- -- [39] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- [3A] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- [3B] ??? 
>   XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX --:--:-- -- XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
>            (unknown key)                 (unknown key)
>
> Sector 15 (0x0F) [3C] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
>   -- -- [3D] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- [3E] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- [3F] ??? 
>   XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX --:--:-- -- XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
>            (unknown key)                 (unknown key)
>
> Sector 16 (0x10) [40] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
>   -- -- [41] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- [42] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- [43] ??? 
>   XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX --:--:-- -- XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
>            (unknown key)                 (unknown key)
>
> Sector 17 (0x11) [44] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
>   -- -- [45] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- [46] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- [47] ??? 
>   XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX --:--:-- -- XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
>            (unknown key)                 (unknown key)
>
> Sector 18 (0x12) [48] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
>   -- -- [49] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- [4A] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- [4B] ??? 
>   XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX --:--:-- -- XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
>            (unknown key)                 (unknown key)
>
> Sector 19 (0x13) [4C] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
>   -- -- [4D] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- [4E] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- [4F] ??? 
>   XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX --:--:-- -- XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
>            (unknown key)                 (unknown key)
>
> Sector 20 (0x14) [50] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
>   -- -- [51] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- [52] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- [53] ??? 
>   XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX --:--:-- -- XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
>            (unknown key)                 (unknown key)
>
> Sector 21 (0x15) [54] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
>   -- -- [55] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- [56] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- [57] ??? 
>   XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX --:--:-- -- XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
>            (unknown key)                 (unknown key)
>
> Sector 22 (0x16) [58] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
>   -- -- [59] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- [5A] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- [5B] ??? 
>   XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX --:--:-- -- XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
>            (unknown key)                 (unknown key)
>
> Sector 23 (0x17) [5C] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
>   -- -- [5D] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- [5E] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- [5F] ??? 
>   XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX --:--:-- -- XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
>            (unknown key)                 (unknown key)
>
> Sector 24 (0x18) [60] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
>   -- -- [61] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- [62] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- [63] ??? 
>   XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX --:--:-- -- XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
>            (unknown key)                 (unknown key)
>
> Sector 25 (0x19) [64] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
>   -- -- [65] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- [66] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- [67] ??? 
>   XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX --:--:-- -- XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
>            (unknown key)                 (unknown key)
>
> Sector 26 (0x1A) [68] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
>   -- -- [69] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- [6A] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- [6B] ??? 
>   XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX --:--:-- -- XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
>            (unknown key)                 (unknown key)
>
> Sector 27 (0x1B) [6C] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
>   -- -- [6D] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- [6E] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- [6F] ??? 
>   XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX --:--:-- -- XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
>            (unknown key)                 (unknown key)
>
> Sector 28 (0x1C) [70] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
>   -- -- [71] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- [72] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- [73] ??? 
>   XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX --:--:-- -- XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
>            (unknown key)                 (unknown key)
>
> Sector 29 (0x1D) [74] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
>   -- -- [75] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- [76] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- [77] ??? 
>   XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX --:--:-- -- XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
>            (unknown key)                 (unknown key)
>
> Sector 30 (0x1E) [78] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
>   -- -- [79] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- [7A] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- [7B] ??? 
>   XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX --:--:-- -- XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
>            (unknown key)                 (unknown key)
>
> Sector 31 (0x1F) [7C] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
>   -- -- [7D] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- [7E] ???  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- [7F] ??? 
>   XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX --:--:-- -- XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
>            (unknown key)                 (unknown key)
>
> r/R=read, w/W=write, i/I=increment, d=decr/transfer/restore, x=r+w,
>   X=R+W data block: r/w/i/d:key A|B, R/W/I:key B only,  I/i implies d,
>   *=value block trailer (order: key A, AC, key B): r/w:key A,  W:key B, R:key A|B, (r)=readable key AC: W implies R+r, R implies r

```swift
...
        guard let session = NFCTagReaderSession(pollingOption: [.iso14443], delegate: self) else { return }
        self.session = session
        session.begin()

...
extension Controller: NFCTagReaderSessionDelegate {
    func tagReaderSessionDidBecomeActive(_ session: NFCTagReaderSession) {
        print("tagReaderSessionDidBecomeActive")
    }

    func tagReaderSession(_ session: NFCTagReaderSession, didInvalidateWithError error: Error) {
        print(error.localizedDiscription)
    }

    func tagReaderSession(_ session: NFCTagReaderSession, didDetect tags: [NFCTag]) {
        print("did detect")
    }
}
```

Comment: Check here. May be you need to enable NFC Tag detection
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44380305/ios-11-core-nfc-any-sample-code

Comment: It looks like this tag is password-protected against reading/writing "(unknown key)"